# undefined method `succesfully_sent?'' , Rails 4 and Devise password recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

My goal is to request password recovery using Ajax.

**My form:**

```
  <%= form_for(resource,:html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true,:id=>"password-recover-modal",:class=>"password-recover-modal"},:remote=> true,format: :json,as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">    
       <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true ,:class=> "user-input form-control", :id=>"email",:placeholder=>"E-pasts",required: true%>                                             
   </div>

    <%= f.submit "Atgūt paroli",:class=> "blue-button btn btn-default"%>

<%end%>
```

I had to override Devise passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

respond_to :json, only: [:create]

  def create
     user = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)

          if succesfully_sent?(user)
               render json: { data: "something" }, status: 200
          else
               render json: { data: "something bad" }, status: 400
          end
  end

end
```

E-mail with password recovery instructions was sent successfully.

**Problem:**

I can't get ajax response  either there was error sending that e-mail or not.

**Eror message:**

```
undefined method `succesfully_sent'
```

Comment: where is succesfully_sent defined?

Comment: Check your spelling: `successfully_sent?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo.

The method is `successfully_sent?` and is defined in the `DeviseController` so should be available to any controller that inherits from it.